# Why are Android apps getting rid of "Quit" functionality?

Tags: applications

Lately I have seen many apps getting rid of the "Quit" functionality. For e.g. older version of Firefox for Android have a Quit option in menu which now is removed. Same goes for Opera browser which had a Quit option in menu which was removed after it moved to Webkit from Presto.

Wouldn't quitting an app be better for Android as it would consume less memory and resources in turn would give better battery life?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8295 . See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/927 for more info about whether the "quit" button actually does anything.